# How to add "rel" attribute to a href of a select element?

Tags: javascript, html

So I have this code:

```
<select onchange="location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" name="fancySelect" class="makeMeFancy">

       <option value="0" selected="selected" data-skip="1">Choose Your Product</option>
       <option value="img/picsamp.jpg" data-icon="img/products/iphone.png" data-html-text="iPhone 4&lt;i&gt;in stock&lt;/i&gt;">iPhone 4</option>
       <option value="2" data-icon="img/products/ipod.png" data-html-text="iPod &lt;i&gt;in stock&lt;/i&gt;">iPod</option>
       <option value="3" data-icon="img/products/air.png" data-html-text="MacBook Air&lt;i&gt;out of stock&lt;/i&gt;">MacBook Air</option>
       <option value="4" data-icon="img/products/imac.png" data-html-text="iMac Station&lt;i&gt;in stock&lt;/i&gt;">iMac Station</option>

</select>
```

With it, I can click on an element and go to the link stored in the "value" attribute. My question is, ¿Can I add a "rel" attribute to that link generated with the onchange? I need to use a **rel** attribute, not a **data-*** one.

**Edit:**

I also need to add **?iframe=true&width=400&height=200** to my links as the lightbox is going to display iframes...

Comment: Why would you want that? Are you trying to track it with GA or something?

Comment: Most likely @veritas was going to suggest an answer that required jQuery (although possibly some other library), and they were checking to see if you had jQuery (or another library) available.

Comment: Yep! jQuery... What I want to do is to add the rel=prettyphoto attribute so when the select element gets clicked the image linked up there in the code display in a prettyphoto lightbox.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wanting open a modal window, then most libraries allow you to programmatically open windows. So, you could write a code block that listens for the select list to change and then manually open a modal window, with the content coming from the URL you have stored in the currently selected option.